# No muentra datos al momento de descargar el excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
<?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "pcomp"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "KneTPuxJ77f4YLNX";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "base";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "reporte"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "rrr"; 

require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $DB_TBLName";
$filename = "CFN"; //your file name

$result123 = mysql_query($sql);

$filename = "CFN"; //your file name
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();



    // Rename 2nd sheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('rrr');
    /*********************Add column headings START**********************/
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B8', 'id ');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C8', 'id_aviso');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D8', 'tipo_defecto');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E8', 'direccion');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F8', 'Agencia');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G8', 'Oficina Central');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H8', 'tipo_cable');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I8', 'cable');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J8', 'armario');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K8', 'cuenta1');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L8', 'cuenta2');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M8', 'cuenta3');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('N8', 'cuenta4');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('O8', 'cuenta5');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('P8', 'fecha_ingreso');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Q8', 'fecha_respuesta_aviso');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('R8', 'fecha_cfn');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('S8', 'estado');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('T8', 'usuario_ingreso_aviso');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('U8', 'usuario_revisar_aviso');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('V8', 'usuario_respuesta_aviso');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('W8', 'es_cfn'); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('X8', 'fecha_cfn_resuelto');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Y8', 'fecha_pruebas');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Z8', 'fecha_cierre');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AA8', 'eecc');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AB8', 'capacidad');
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AC8', 'estado2');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AD8', 'causa_falla');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AE8', 'falla_prueba');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AF8', 'contador_falla_prueba');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AG8', 'es_localizado');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AH8', 'nom_tecnico');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AI8', 'nom_gestor');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AJ8', 'horas_quiebre');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AK8', 'descripcion_quiebre');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AL8', 'tipo_quiebre');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AM8', 'fecha_quiebre');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AN8', 'par');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AO8', 'servicio');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AP8', 'n_clientes');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AQ8', 'zona');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AR8', 'eecc_ere');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AS8', 'Horas');

    $row = 9; // 1-based index
    while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result123)) {
        $col = 1;
        foreach($row_data as $key=>$value) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
            $col++;
        }
        $row++;
    }

    foreach(range('B','AR') as $columnID) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setWidth(40);
    }

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B7:AR8')->getFont()->setBold(true); //Make heading font bold


    /*********************Add color to heading START**********************/

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->getStyle('B8:AR8')
                ->getFill()
                ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
                ->getStartColor()
                ->setARGB('99ff99');
    /*********************Add color to heading END***********************/

    $objDrawing5 = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
    $objDrawing5->setName('Sample image');
    $objDrawing5->setDescription('Sample image');
    $objDrawing5->setImageResource($gdImage);
    $objDrawing5->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
    $objDrawing5->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
    $objDrawing5->setHeight(70);
    $objDrawing5->setCoordinates('A1');
    $objDrawing5->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=$filename.xls");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Seguro que la consulta sí encuentra datos? Sale algún error en los logs? P.D. PHPexcel está descontinuada, considera usar PHPSpreadsheet

Comment: si la consulta esta bien tambien probe con otro codigo que subi en una publicacion anterior no me aparece otro error solo me descarga y al momento de abrir salen solos los encabezados